# Wish to add and change colors in table cells as one might with excel

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have created a table in SharePoint using Table and Table Layout features. I wish to be able to add and change colors of the table cells as a living document. Can someone help me out with this please?  I am using SharePoint Server 2013. Thank you

Comment: You added the table using the "Table" control from the ribbon to the Content Editor Web part?

Comment: Yes, under Insert then Insert Table. Then Table Layout to insert a few more columns. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below to format the table added to the Content Editor Web Part.

1. Edit Web Part.
2. Click on "Format Text" tab from the ribbon.
   [image]
3. Click Edit Source to edit the code where you can add rows, columns or format text using HTML code.

[image]

4. Click "Ok" button to save changes.
5. Save the page.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try. Thanks for taking the time to lay this out for me.